# Repeat method chain over for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to repeat and stack on methods to a chain depending on length `x`;

```
const thing = ObjWithMethods
thing
  .something()
  .somethingElse()
  .repeat(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      thing.repeatedMethod()
    }
  })
  .endMethods();
```

Is there a way to do this?

Edit:
This is the current concrete example I have

```
import HummusRecipe from 'hummus-recipe';
const getPageCount = require('docx-pdf-pagecount');
const generateFooterText = (index, length) => `Page ${index} / ${length}`;

const applyPdfFooter = (input, output, cb) => {
  const throwErr = (err) => {cb(err);};
  const recipe = new HummusRecipe(input, output, pdfOptions);
  getPageCount(input)
    .then((pages) => {
      console.log('Pages: ', pages);
      recipe
        .and(function(recipe) {
          for (let i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
            const text = generateFooterText(i, pages);
            recipe
              .editPage(i)
              .text(text, 0, 0)
              .endPage();
          }
        })
        .endPDF();
      cb();
    })
    .catch(throwErr);
};
export default applyPdfFooter;
```

Comment: I am looking for a correct syntax that is applicable for methods like this.  My google-kata only showed my an example using `Selenium Node.JS adapter` and their `browser.chain()`.  Is `.and()` a proper generalized method to use for this?

Comment: @melpomene I want to repeat a method on a method chain `x` times, where `x` is a number determined on other data.

Comment: What do you mean by "repeat a method on a method chain"? Can you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

your recipe could be implemented as:

```
 class Recipe {
    constructor(input, output, options) {
      this.page = 0;
    }

    and(fn) {
      fn(this);
      return this; // chaining
   }

   editPage(i) {
     this.page = i;
     return this;
   }

   text(...args) {
    //...
    return this;
   }

   endPage() {
    this.page++;
    return this;
   }

   endPdf() { }
 }
```

... but I'm not sure if that `and(...)` method has any benefit...,